# Python - writing to SQL server database using sqlalchemy from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a pandas dataframe of approx 300,000 rows (20mb), and want to write to a SQL server database.

I have the following code but it is very very slow to execute. Wondering if there is a better way?

```
import pandas
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://rea-eqx-dwpb/BIWorkArea? 
driver=SQL+Server')

df.to_sql(name='LeadGen Imps&Clicks', con=engine, schema='BIWorkArea', 
if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816918/write-large-pandas-dataframes-to-sql-server-database  : I would have closed as duplicate but I didn't find linked answer right away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write Large Pandas DataFrames to SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816918/write-large-pandas-dataframes-to-sql-server-database) @MitchWheat Got it for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speeding up pandas.DataFrame.to\_sql with fast\_executemany of pyODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc)

Comment: `pyodbc` used to have issues with large `executemany()` batches, which `to_sql()` uses under the hood. The `fast_executemany` flag should solve that to some degree (>100x speedups).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to speed up you process with writing into the sql database , you can per-setting the dtypes of the table in your database by the data type of your `pandas` `DataFrame`

```
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine
d={}
for k,v in zip(df.dtypes.index,df.dtypes):
    if v=='object':
       d[k]=types.VARCHAR(df[k].str.len().max())
    elif v=='float64':
       d[k]=types.FLOAT(126)
    elif v=='int64':
       d[k] = types.INTEGER()
```

Then

```
df.to_sql(name='LeadGen Imps&Clicks', con=engine, schema='BIWorkArea', if_exists='replace', index=False,dtype=d)
```